# how to send xml response to a given url from express route?

Tags: node.js, xml, express, response

I need to send a XML response from express route to an url given as a POST Request?

```
const xml = `<sourcedGUID>
             <sourcedId>ASSMT12345</sourcedId>
</sourcedGUID>
<contextID>
    <textString>cls1234</textString>
</contextID>
<userID>
    <textString>usr123</textString>
</userID>`
```

I am in express route of /status and I need to send the xml variable to the url: 'https://example.com/cli' using express.

How can I achieve this use case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like `request` or `axios` or `http`, I will use `request` here

```
var request = require('request');

request.post({
    url: <the-url-where-to-send-xml>,
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
    },
    body: xml
},
function(error, response, body){
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    console.log(body);
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Will it send to a custom url? or it will send it back to the requested ?

Comment: It's what you send back to the request, if you add more code i can be more precise

Comment: Suppose there are two urls : https: example1.com and https: example2.com

So, you send request from  https: example1.com and need to send response back to example2.com as xml data